# Is there a way to have knitr/R show you how much data was processed?

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to have knitr or your R scripts show you what files have been processed, and how much data was loaded into R scripts?

An example could be (simple summary stats on datasets):

```
myfile1.csv       1.2g
someotherfile.xml 291m
```

What is the best way to cascade this into my document compilation?

Comment: So you're looking for the file sizes of the files that have been loaded during your analysis? Did you look at `file.info` yet?

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect, I guess I'll just write that out to a text file.

Comment: Why can't you just include it in your script and not echo it until the end or wherever you want to put your summary?

Comment: How would you keep track of all files loaded across 14 scripts that process multiple datasets?

Comment: One way would be to wrap your calls to whatever function you're using to read in data (`read.csv()`, or `load()` or whatever) in a function that also records the size of the the file that it loads, perhaps appending it to a growing data.frame.

Comment: How would I know that you have 14 scripts that process multiple datasets? Still don't see how it would be a problem. It all depends on how you set up your data loading/processing before using Knitr. It should be pretty easy to create an empty `list` or even an empty vector and insert it at the relevant point in your document.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks. Josh a wrapper function came to mind. I haven't used 'global' variables yet that run across multiple Rnw files, maybe you can point me in a direction? Or can I assume that everything where I stipulate cached is available everywhere else?